# function would not change the parameter as wanted

Tags: python, dictionary

here is my code

```
def common_words(count_dict, limit):
    '''
    >>> k = {'you':2, 'made':1, 'me':1}
    >>> common_words(k,2)
    >>> k
    {'you':2}
    '''
    new_list = list(revert_dictionary(count_dict).items())[::-1]
    count_dict = {}
    for number,word in new_list:
        if len(count_dict) + len(word) <= limit:
            for x in word:
                count_dict[x] = number

    print (count_dict)





def revert_dictionary(dictionary):
    '''
    >>> revert_dictionary({'sb':1, 'QAQ':2, 'CCC':2})
    {1: ['sb'], 2: ['CCC', 'QAQ']}
    '''
    reverted = {}
    for key,value in dictionary.items():
        reverted[value] = reverted.get(value,[]) + [key]
    return reverted


count_dict = {'you':2, 'made':1, 'me':1}
common_words(count_dict,2)
print (count_dict)
```

what i expected is to have the count_dict variable to change to {'you':2}.
It did work fine in the function's print statement, but not outside the function..

Comment: You have to return *count_dict* at the end of the function and use the returned value afterwards. The variables modified inside a function only belong to that function's namespace if you don't declare them as global. For getting a variable value outside a function's scope, you have to use the *return* statement

Comment: but the return type of this function is None. The purpose of this function is to take what is sent in and change the thing itself

Comment: `count_dict = {}` means you are creating a new local dictionary and no longer working on the one that has been passed into the function. Any way it is not really Pythonic to modify a dictionary that has been passed in as a parameter, you should always `return` the result you want

Comment: the print (count_dict) statement is just for me to test my code

Comment: Just try as I told you an it'll work. at the end of *common_words()* function, type `return count_dict`. And when you call this function at the end, modify it and type instead: `count_dict = common_words(count_dict,2)`

Comment: Thank you for the comment UnholySheep. Would having a new variable replace the code "count_dict = {}" and then make count_dict equal to that variable help?

Comment: Thank you Jalo. But the requirement is not to return anything. I would use the way you said if i was allowed

Comment: Nope, that would also not modify the passed in dictionary. If you want to achieve what you apparently are trying to do then you can **not** write `count_dict = ...` inside your function

Comment: Why can't you return anything? the other solution is naming count_dict as global inside the function

Comment: What exactly is the condition `if len(count_dict) + len(word) <= limit:` supposed to achieve? Do you only want to keep the `limit` most common words?

Comment: Cause I'm trying to finish an assignment and that's apparently the requirement by the professor.... we arent allow to use global too

Comment: @GavinWong just removing the line `count_dict = {}` might (maybe?) achieve the desired result

Comment: Well, one rather cheap solution would be to `del` all the elements from the original dict and re-ropulate it with the stuff from the new one.

Comment: the variable limit is to set a limit of how many keys you can have in the new count_dict. For example the example I had above should have only {'you':2} because adding keys with value 1 will exceed the limit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already mentioned, the problem is that with `count_dict = {}` you are not changing the passed in dictionary, but you create a new one, and all subsequent changes are done on that new dictionary. The classical approach would be to just return the new dict, but it seems like you can't do that.

Alternatively, instead of adding the values to a new dictionary, you could reverse your condition and delete values from the existing dictionary. You can't use `len(count_dict)` in the condition, though, and have to use another variable to keep track of the elements already "added" to (or rather, not removed from) the dictionary.

```
def common_words(count_dict, limit):
    new_list = list(revert_dictionary(count_dict).items())[::-1]
    count = 0
    for number,word in new_list:
        if count + len(word) > limit:
            for x in word:
                del count_dict[x]
        else:
            count += len(word)
```

Also note that the dict returned from `revert_dictionary` does not have a particular order, so the line `new_list = list(revert_dictionary(count_dict).items())[::-1]` is not guaranteed to give you the `items` in any particular order, as well. You might want to add `sorted` here and sort by the count, but I'm not sure if you actually want that.

```
new_list = sorted(revert_dictionary(count_dict).items(), reverse=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem, as others have already written, is that your function assigns a *new* empty dictionary to `count_dict`:

```
count_dict = {}
```

When you do this you modify the local variable `count_dict`, but the variable with the same name in the main part of your program continues to point to the original dictionary.

You should understand that you *are* allowed to modify the dictionary you passed in the function argument; just don't replace it with a new dictionary. To get your code to work without modifying anything else, you can instead delete all elements of the *existing* dictionary:

```
count_dict.clear()
```

This modifies the dictionary that was passed to the function, deleting all its elements-- which is what you intended. That said, if you are performing a new calculation it's usually a better idea to create a new dictionary in your function, and return it with `return`.

Answer (score -1):

just write

```
return count_dict
```

below

```
print count_dict
```

in function common_words()

and change

```
common_words(count_dict,2)
```

to

```
count_dict=common_words(count_dict,2)
```

So basically you need to return value from function and store that in your variable. When you are calling function and give it a parameter. It sends its copy to that function not variable itself.

Comment: if you dont want to return anything. Dont pass count_dict parameter to function. It will automatically take global count_dict variable